# Route missing when using jquery-ui on ror project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use the button widget of jquery-ui in my ror project.

I added the jquery-1.5.1.min.js file in the public/javascripts folder, and included it in the application.html.erb file as below:

```
  #application.html.erb
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-1.5.1.min" %> 
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min" %>
```

Then one of my routes stops working.

```
  # routes.rb
  controller :sessions do
    get 'login'  =>  :new
    post 'login'  =>  :create
    delete 'logout'  => :destroy
  end

  #application.html.erb
  <%= link_to image_tag("Arrow Left 2.png"), logout_path, :method => :delete, :class  => "barlink" %>
```

The button effect works, but When I click on the logout link, it gives the following error:

> Routing Error
>
> No route matches "/logout"

I also tried to switch the order of the scripts as:

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-1.5.1.min" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

For this case, the route works, but my button effect disappears.

Any idea?

Comment: have you try execute "rake routes" fron console inside your apps directory ?

Comment: Thanks Kav1nsky, I just did 'rake routes' and it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

- add the following line in GemFile

  gem 'jquery-rails'
- run

  sudo bundle install
- run

  rails generate jquery:install -ui -force

then i can either use the jquery-min provided or the jquery-1.5.1.min without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to {:controller => 'sessions', :action => "destroy"}, :method => :delete, :class  => "barlink" do %>
   <%= image_tag("Arrow Left 2.png")  %>
<% end %>
```

I've problem similiar like you and solve by that snippet code... may it help you, thx